# Error while running app in Android studio, build fail

Tags: android-studio, build-error

Im trying to run my project in android studio but I get the error message
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Johan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I have no idea what to do. Was able to run the app earlier and dont even know what changed.

Comment: You don't have any other error? If no, show us your code

Comment: I solved it by cleaning and rebuilding the project. Dont know why it worked though.